# How to display Java Source Code in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, awt, desktop-application

I am designing a Swing Application to open a Java Program from `.java` file and save it to same.

My question is how will I display the Java program in `JTextArea` or any other editor with proper formatting, designing and Indentation.

Right now I use `JTextArea` & get something like this, which is not so soothing:

[image: Right now I get something like this, which is not at so soothing]

Any suggestion how I may make it look better?

Comment: Please tell us more about "not so soothing". How is this display not working? Perhaps all you need/want to do is to change the JTextArea's Font, but it is difficult for any of us to say without more specific information as to exactly what your problem is.

Comment: If you mean to context color words for a Java source editor, that requires a styled document, where a `JTextArea` supports only plain text (one font, font size, style and color). For a styled document, use a `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels by "soothing" I mean proper handling of indentations. thats my only consideration.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thankyou very much. it was a great help